# Minecraft Crashing when I join server or open a world

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When I launch vanilla Minecraft 1.8.8, and try to load a server or a world, Minecraft crashes.

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
# EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000000001d55c933, pid=13152, tid=12108
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_25-b18) (build 1.8.0_25-b18)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.25-b02 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C [ig7icd64.dll+0x6c933]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:UsersJackAppDataRoaming.minecrafths_err_pid13152.log
Compiled method (c1) 14863 5424 2 bmt::a (11 bytes)
total in heap [0x00000000034c8610,0x00000000034c8f90] = 2432
relocation [0x00000000034c8730,0x00000000034c87c0] = 144
main code [0x00000000034c87c0,0x00000000034c8ac0] = 768
stub code [0x00000000034c8ac0,0x00000000034c8bb8] = 248
oops [0x00000000034c8bb8,0x00000000034c8bc0] = 8
metadata [0x00000000034c8bc0,0x00000000034c8c00] = 64
scopes data [0x00000000034c8c00,0x00000000034c8e78] = 632
scopes pcs [0x00000000034c8e78,0x00000000034c8f68] = 240
dependencies [0x00000000034c8f68,0x00000000034c8f70] = 8
nul chk table [0x00000000034c8f70,0x00000000034c8f90] = 32
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
# http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

What can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Try reinstalling Java, or if you have Java 8, [try installing Java 7](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre7-downloads-1880261.html).

You can find more information [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Minecraft/comments/39ucin/my_minecraft_keeps_crashing_after_i_load_into_a/).